# Notes value surpass the time signature of 4/4

Tags: notation, time-signatures

I'm playing on an acoustic guitar.
I've just started learning notes notation and I can't understand how this should be played, as the value of notes seems to be larger than the 4/4 rhythm.

From what I understand, the notes with the stem up represent one voice, and stem down represent another voice.

So if I just look at the notes with the stem up, their value is 5 :S

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The circled notes are *grace notes*.

You can see that the note heads are slightly smaller than the other note heads. That's the visual clue they are grace notes.

You perform them quickly before the third beat.

So beat 2 would be played more like a dotted eight with grace notes like two 32nd notes. Although the exact speed is open to interpretation. It could be executed like an 8th and two 16ths. Given that the graces are visually *after* the synopated 8th in the lower voice (the tied note) it seems like 32nd notes make more sense so they aren't play at the same time as the tied note.

[image]